# How to add background color to row based on column value?

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I am using react smart data table, based on the column value want to add background color to the row

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-smart-data-table

link to the smart data table I am using

```
Table header 
        ID: {
            text: 'ID',
            transform: value => `${value}`,
            className : 'column-Class',
        },
        name: {
            text: 'Name',
            transform: value => `${value}`,
        },
        Country: {
            text: 'Country',
            transform: value => `${value}`,
        }
```

I tried to add background color by adding `className` to the column and the css exists in the `.css` file

Comment: Are you importing the css file?

Comment: Seems you have missed CSS import

Comment: @KieranQuinn and Jayanti Lal yes my CSS file is perfectly imported here. want to know this is how we have to add color or is there any other way.